# Input validation numeric on the Keyboard,check if the textbox is empty

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I have implemented a login, where within this login I have entered 2 textboxes, one for the username and one for the password. Underneath the textBoxes there I have inserted a numeric keypad and now I would like to do validation of the numbers pressed on the keypad.
I have set up that if the tetxBox is empty, the labeltext returns me an error, what I plan to do is to check if the input is correct it signals me that it is correct and then by pressing the enter button, I can write on the next textBox, if on the other hand the textbox is invalid it does not make me go to the next textBox

please help me, I am going crazy about it :)

```
  private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_nomeUtente.Text))
        {


            label6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            label6.Text = "username empty, cannot be left empty";
            txt_nomeUtente.Text += ((Button)sender).Text;




        }
        else
        {
            label6.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            label6.Text = "username is acceptable";
            txt_Password.Text += ((Button)sender).Text;




            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_Password.Text))
            {
                label6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label6.Text = " password is empty";

            }
            else
            {
                label6.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                label6.Text = "La password is acceptable";

            }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to focus on the user name if they enter an invalid user name and on the password if the user name is valid:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Check_User_Input
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label6.Text = txt_nomeUtente.Text.Length.ToString("N0");
        }

        private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckForValidEntries();
        }

        private void CheckForValidEntries()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_nomeUtente.Text))
            {
                label6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label6.Text = "username empty, cannot be left empty";
                //txt_nomeUtente.Text += ((Button)sender).Text;
            }
            else
            {
                label6.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                label6.Text = "username is acceptable";
                txt_Password.Focus();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_Password.Text))
                {
                    label6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    label6.Text = " password is empty";
                }
                else
                {
                    label6.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    label6.Text = "La password is acceptable";
                }
            }
        }

        private void txt_nomeUtente_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                CheckForValidEntries();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The main porblem is that when I comment those 2 lines, when I fill in the first textBox and it turns out to be correct, when I fill in the second textbox it is entered in the first textbox, inoltee I would like to use the numeric keypad to be able to type

Comment: What do you mean by "inoltee"? Please elaborate on "I would like to use the numeric keypad to be able to type." Do you only want the user to be able to enter numbers and no other characters?

Comment: yes, I've already blocked the special characters, what I want to do is to verify that the input is correct, so that I can move on to the next textbox, so I fill in the first textbox after which I press enter and if the validation is successful it makes me fill in the next textbox, otherwise if it's not successful it doesn't make me move on to the next textbox.
when I try to run the application and fill in the first textbox, it gets validated perfectly but it doesn't go on to the second labelbox, so what I type from the keypad stays on the first textbox.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is `txt_Password.Focus()` instead of `txt_Password.Text += ((Button)sender).Text`.

Comment: also tried with focus but it doesn't go, there is another detail. when I try to click the enter button on the keypad it brings back "ENTER" on both boxes, as if the ENTER button is not recognized

Comment: Add a KeyDown event handler, and check for the Enter key being pressed:
`private void txt_nomeUtente_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                CheckForValidEntries();
        }`

Comment: send is on the keypad I created on the login page

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "send is on the keypad."

Comment: that is basically I when I click enter from the keypad that I use to type numbers, when I click enter the validation happens, however if the validation is correct it doesn't make me write on the other textbox but only stays on the previous one

Comment: I updated the code in my answer above to include a txt_nomeUtente_KeyDown event handler. I also moved your form validation into a method named CheckForValidEntries and called it from txt_nomeUtente_KeyDown and button15_Click. See if that does what you need.

Comment: no, it still doesn't go..,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).